# Android Studio Nexus 7

Tags: android, nexus-7

I'm running Android Studio 1.4 on Windows 10.  Windows recognizes my Nexus 7 but it doesn't show up in Android Studio.  I'm probably overlooking something obvious but I've searched everywhere I can think of and haven't found anything pertinent.  Which makes me think I'm doing something dumb. Or  maybe not doing something that should be obvious.

Comment: what happens when you `adb devices` from command line/terminal/prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable USB Debugging on your device? If yes may be ADB driver is missing?

To enable USB debugging you need to do the following steps: 
1) Go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom. 
2) Go to Developer Options and check USB Debbuging option.